# ¿Como puedo enviar un mail con php y laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Buenas tardes compañeros, me encuentro realizando un formulario para enviar correos, el detalle que tengo es que al momento de enviar el mail, si me encuentro en mi localhost si envia el email exitosamente, al subirlo a un servidor me arroja un error y por ende no se envia dicho email.

Les comparto la funcion que estoy realizando para el envio del email.

```
public function postStoreJobsForm(request $request){

    $nombre = $request['nombre'];
    $email = $request['email'];
    $telefono= $request['telefono'];
    $marca= $request['marca'];
    $modelo= $request['modelo'];
    $puertas= $request['puertas'];
    $color= $request['color'];
    $trasmision= $request['trasmision'];
    $cilindros= $request['cilindros'];
    $kilometraje= $request['kilometraje'];
    $estadoInterior= $request['estadoInterior'];
    $precio= $request['precio'];

    $input = Input::all();

    Mail::send('web.front.email.jobs', [
        'nombre' => $nombre, 
        'email' => $email,  
        'telefono' => $telefono,
        'marca' => $marca,
        'modelo' => $modelo,
        'puertas' => $puertas,
        'color' => $color,
        'trasmision' => $trasmision,
        'cilindros' => $cilindros,
        'kilometraje' => $kilometraje,
        'estadoInterior' => $estadoInterior,
         'precio' => $precio], function ($message) use ($input, $nombre, $email) {
            $message->from($email, $nombre);
            $message->sender('ing.magalylf@hotmail.com', 'Bolsa de trabajo');
         /*Correo para enviar a otras personas */
            $message->to('magaly.lopez@metodika.mx', 'Magaly');
            /*$message->cc('ALSanchez@terza.com', 'ALSanchez');
            $message->cc('rrodriguez@terza.com', 'rrodriguez');
            $message->cc('rjagarza@terza.com', 'rjagarza');
            $message->cc('rjagarza@terza.com', 'rjagarza');
            $message->bcc('bruno.chavez@metodika.mx', 'Bruno Chavez');;*/
            $message->bcc('azeneth.futurite@gmail.com', 'Azeneth');

            $message->subject('Quiero Vender Mi Auto');

            $message->priority(3);

            $message->attach($input['archivo']->getRealPath(), array(
            'as' => 'archivo.' . $input['archivo']->getClientOriginalExtension(), 
            'mime' => $input['archivo']->getMimeType()));

             return view('web.front.ofreceAuto');
        });
return redirect()->intended('/web.front.ofreceAuto/');

 }
```

Y este es el error que me arroja:

```
(1/1) ReflectionException
Class Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler does not exist
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme les agradecere mucho...

les comparto el enlace para que puedan ver el error a detalle:
PD. rellenan el formulario con cualquier dato e intentan enviar el email

http://testingmetodika.com/autos-dieck/public/ofrece-tu-auto

Espero haberme explicado bien, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Yo obtuve un error distinto: `Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host ...`

Comment: @Shaz Ese error es por el puerto MAIL_PORT que esta en el archivo .env debes de poner el que proporciona tu proveedor de correo.